# How to specify the CFLAGS parameter in go build command line instead of in the go source file？

Tags: go, cgo

For example, the MY_NUM in go file:

```golang
//#cgo CFLAGS: -DMY_NUM=3
/*
int multiple(int x) {
    return x * MY_NUM;
}
*/
import "C"

....
```

But I will often change the value of MY_NUM. So I want change it in build command.

How can I define it in `go build` command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not exactly a `go build` option, but you could use the `CGO_CFLAGS` environment variable, e.g.:

```
$ cat foo.go
package main

/*
int multiple(int x) {
        return x * MY_NUM;
}
*/
import "C"

import "fmt"

func main() {
        fmt.Println(C.multiple(2))
}
$ CGO_CFLAGS="-DMY_NUM=10" go build foo.go
$ ./foo
20
$
```

from https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/cgo

> When building, the CGO_CFLAGS, CGO_CPPFLAGS, CGO_CXXFLAGS, CGO_FFLAGS
> and CGO_LDFLAGS environment variables are added to the flags derived
> from these directives. Package-specific flags should be set using the
> directives, not the environment variables, so that builds work in
> unmodified environments. Flags obtained from environment variables are
> not subject to the security limitations described above.

Comment: It works, thank you very much.